# How To Get Rid of Scroll Bar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbars

It's at the bottom of [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/) in Chrome.

I can't see what would be putting it there.

Thank you,

Tara

Comment: I'm using Chrome and don't see a scroll bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
div#wrapper
{
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: whats the @ and how to get it and what does it mean?

Comment: you can check this topic to understand what @ means http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the #footbar element.